# What's the source that Eretz Yisroel was promised by Hashem?

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, avot-patriarch-fathers

I am looking for sources on the topic of when Hashem promised Eretz Yisroel to the Avos. If there's anyone who can help me, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi c Fischer, and [welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! There are plenty of p'sukim in Sefer B'reishis, including HaShem promising the land to Avraham in 12:7; 13:15,17; 15:7,16,18; 17:8,19,21; Avraham recalling the promise in 24:7; HaShem promising Yitzchak in 26:3,4; Yitzchak bestowing the blessing to Ya'akov in 28:4; HaShem promising Ya'akov in 28:13-15; 35:12; Ya'akov recalling the promise in 48:4-6,21-22; Yosef recalling the promise in 50:24. There are also many other p'sukim throughout the Chumash and Tanach that refer to this promise.

Comment: See also the Gemara in Bava Basra 119b. See: https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.119b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: See also this article: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/92910/jewish/Pinchas-Portion-Lot-and-Inheritance.htm